# Laravel search for specific contain word on 2 columns

Tags: php, laravel

I got a problem when search query using Laravel where and like.

```
$words = 'as';

$query = Category::where(function ($query) use ($words) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', $words. '%')
                      ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'. $words . '%')
                      ->orWhere('location_name', 'like', $words.'%')
                      ->orWhere('location_name', 'like', '%'. $words . '%')
                })->pluck('name', 'location_name');
```

The result is:

```
[{name: Chocolate Spa, location_name: Throne Glass}]
```

The expected result is empty.

I want it search name and location name column starts with the given word not contain that words.

How can I achieve that search method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
Category::where(function ($q) use ($keywords) {
    $q->where('name', 'like', $keywords . '%')
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', '% ' . $keywords . '%');
});
->orWhere(function ($q) use ($keywords) {
    $q->where('location_name', 'like', $keywords . '%')
        ->orWhere('location_name', 'like', '% ' . $keywords . '%');
});
```

Comment: You're still including a wildcard before the keywords. In your first example searching for " Spa" (note the space) would return a result which you indicated you didn't want.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're using the MySQL wildcard symbol ('%') before and after your word. This will match anything where it contains the word. If you just want it to start with the word, you just want to match the wildcard at the end not the beginning.

Try this.

```
$words = 'as';

$query = Category::where('name', 'like', $words . '%')
                -> orWhere('location_name', 'like', $words .'%')
                -> pluck('name', 'location_name');
```

Comment: Had given you the method for ends with not starts with - try the corrected answer.

Comment: it working but, if name is "the caramel". it will return me empty.

Comment: I found the solution using advanced where from laravel